# Symfony listener - postUpdate doublon

Tags: symfony, doctrine, event-listener, symfony-3.4

I'm running Symfony 3 LTS.
I have a Suscriber listening to the `postUpdate` event in order to log into DB all the activity on products in my database. Below is my code:

```
use AppBundle\Entity\History;

public function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        Events::postUpdate,
    ];
}

public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    if(!is_null($this->tokenStorage->getToken())) {
        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
        $entity = $args->getObject();
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        if ($entity instanceof Product) {
            $history = new History($user, "Product #5 has been updated");
            $em->persist($history);
        }
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

Problem: `History` is inserted twice in the database. I can't figure out why. I tried to remove the `persist()` and/or `flush()` methods but nothing is created.

PS: there is no relationship between my entities `Product` and `History`. And it must not. My issue is only the duplicate behavior.

[image]

Comment: Calling `flush()` when inside a `LifecycleEvent` is not supported, and can have side effects as the one you are experiencing. Calling `EntityManager::persist()` should be enough

Comment: @yivi If I remove the `$em->flush()` my `history` is not inserted anymore. If not the good way to do it, how to log my entitty activity then? I'm lost!

Comment: @yivi See [link](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/faep/listening-on-an-entity-with-an-entity-listener)

Comment: A workaround is to create an array and store into the userId and flush it only if the array does not contains the userId.

Comment: Exemple here https://3v4l.org/qZNNv

Comment: @Smaïne Sorry, I don't understand how to use your workaround to solve my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the correct answer but there is a workaround :

```php
use AppBundle\Entity\History;

    // Will contains the User ID to avoid duplicate log
    private $flushed = [];

    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            Events::postUpdate,
        ];
    }

    public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        if(!is_null($this->tokenStorage->getToken())) {
            $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
            $entity = $args->getObject();
            $em = $args->getEntityManager();
                                            // Check that the User.id is not already created in History during the update PHP Process
            if ($entity instanceof Product && !in_array($user->getId(), $this->flushed)) {
                $history = new History($user, "Product #5 has been updated");
                $em->persist($history);
                // Add the user ID in our array to avoid duplicate
                $this->flushed[] = $user->getId();
            }
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
```